# Execute a script in a cisco switch/router

Tags: java, acl, router, cisco

I'm doing a java software which has to run a script on a Cisco switch / router. This script will configure an ACL on the router. How I can run that script on the router? Or what is the same, how can I pass the script to the router to run it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to execute scripts in IOS, is to run them in the CLI command prompt accessed via telnet or ssh.

The unpopular way to run interactive scripts on IOS is via Cisco TCL
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/netmgmt/configuration/guide/12_2sx/nm_12_2sx_book/nm_script_tcl.pdf

Honestly most people prefer to KISS here. and just open an ssh prompt in java, then 'config t' and paste or input you access-list commands Pretty simple and easy to automate in any language.

depending on your version of IOS however and what access-lists you are adding the syntax for your execution may change however. It would be wise to confirm the end router/switch is running an appropriate version of IOS before attempting to modify ACLS.

'show ver' is a good place to start.